# Changing a Type's Underlying Value via a Method in Golang

Tags: go, types

Can an instance of a go type change its underlying value?  Thanks to a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51507950/can-an-instance-of-a-go-type-change-its-underlying-value) I know I can [make my function's receiver a pointer and change struct fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40953040/why-does-the-setage-method-not-set-the-age-correctly) if my type is a struct.

However, I'm interesting in changing the underlying type's value.  Consider a small program like this

```
type Foo string

func (f *Foo) ChangeMe() {
  val := Foo("Hello World")
  f = &val
  //fmt.Println(*f)
}

func main() {
  f := Foo("Nope")
  f.ChangeMe()
  fmt.Println(f)
}
```

My naive assumption was "OK, I've created a new `Foo("Hello World")` and then pointed `f` at it.  Since receiver is a pointer (`*Foo`), this should change the value in `main()`.

However, this does not work.  The above program still prints out "Nope"

Interested both in what my incorrect assumption about go are, and any techniques for achieving what I want to do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're assigning a new pointer value to `f` instead of dereferencing it.

Dereference `f` and assign a new string value:

```
func (f *Foo) ChangeMe() {
    *f = Foo("Hello World")
}
```